# How to set up localization in react project?

Tags: reactjs, localization

I want to implement multiple language (localization) for my ecommerce project based on reactjs.
can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: read about  `react-intl`  -> https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Answer (score 2):

One of the most popular localization package for react is *react-i18next*

**Before: Your react code would have looked something like:**

```js
...
<div>Just simple content</div>
<div>
  Hello <strong title="this is your name">{name}</strong>, you have {count} unread message(s). <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</div>
...
```

**After: With the trans component just change it to:**

```js
...
<div>{t('simpleContent')}</div>
<Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
  Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message. <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</Trans>
...
```

Ref: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next